# How to tell the number of wins with any given civ?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-de

In Age of Empires II DE there are special icons for when you win 10 and 100 times with any given civilization. Is it possible to see how many wins you have with each civ towards the icons without manually counting the results from saved replays? I can find number of total wins and my "best" civilization, but I can't find per-civ statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can see this directly in-game. But you can sign into your profile on the [official website](https://www.ageofempires.com/stats?game=age2) and check your stats.

Comment: I've looked at that but I have had some trouble interpreting it. There's a bar graph for civilization experience but it doesn't give anything numerical, and it shows I've played the most with a civ that I can't remember ever playing with. Am I missing a submenu or something?

Comment: Sign in, go to My Stats under your icon (top right)
Make sure to choose Age of Empires II : DE from the dropdown (Not selected by default)
Then choose the right game mode and you should be set.
I can see numerical values, myself. For example 10 wins with Franks, 13 with Byzantines, etc.

The stats do seem a bit wonky, to be fair. My campaign stats don't appear to have been recorded at all, even if I have completed several.

Comment: Well, I'm certainly confused. Following that for age 1 gives me exactly the numerical stats I would expect, but for age 2 I get the same non-numerical bar graph. I'll report back if I figure it out. Definitely helps to have the confirmation that I'm (supposedly) looking in the correct place, thanks!

Comment: @qfwfq Yes, the stats are a bit surprising sometimes because of what is and isn't counted. I don't know all the details, but I know that my number of plays with the Byzantines is inflated because of playing the Art of War Early Economy challenge over and over (in which you play as the Byzantines).